# Using google apps script to search and replace in formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, replace, formula

I have a script that makes a copy of 2 master spreadsheets each month.  The sheet names always include the month and 2 digit year. For example, this month the sheets are called Oct23worksheet and Oct23schedule.  In the Oct23schedule sheet, there are several formulas that reference Oct23worksheet.  I've been manually updating the formulas each month using the google sheets find and replace functionality but I would like to automate this task and add it to my script.   Specifically, I want to search only the formulas in the Oct23schedule sheet, find the word master in each formula and replace it with Oct23.

I think this is possible but I don't even know what to search for in order to learn about doing this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `createTextFinder` See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources and more details. Search it in official documentation. Also search that here in SO for code samples.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey Kiribe, any luck?

Comment: Thank you for the detailed suggestions. I've had a few interruptions and haven't been able to study/implement your ideas.  And, I'm getting ready to go out of town for a few weeks so it might be November before I can get back to this project.  Thank you again and I will let you know how things worked out.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function createNewMonthlySheets() {

  // Update with IDs
  const masterWorksheetId = `*****`
  const masterScheduleId = `*****`
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(`*****`)

  const monthYear = (() => {
    const date = new Date()
    const month = [
      `Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar`, `Apr`,
      `May`, `Jun`, `Jul`, `Aug`,
      `Sep`, `Oct`, `Nov`, `Dec`
    ][date.getMonth()]
    const year = String(date.getFullYear()).slice(-2)

    return `${month}${year}`
  })()

  DriveApp
    .getFileById(masterWorksheetId)
    .makeCopy(`${monthYear}worksheet`, destinationFolder)

  const newSchedule = DriveApp
    .getFileById(masterScheduleId)
    .makeCopy(`${monthYear}schedule`, destinationFolder)

  SpreadsheetApp
    .openById(newSchedule.getId())
    .getSheets()
    .forEach((sheet) => {

      const range = sheet.getDataRange()
      const values = range.getValues()

      const newValues = range
        .getFormulas()
        .map((row, rowIndex) => {
          return row
            .map((cell, cellIndex) => (cell !== ``)
              ? cell.replace(/master/g, monthYear)
              : values[rowIndex][cellIndex]
            )
        })

      range.setValues(newValues)

    })

  SpreadsheetApp.flush()

}
```

Commented:

```
function createNewMonthlySheets() {

  // Update with IDs
  const masterWorksheetId = `*****`
  const masterScheduleId = `*****`
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(`*****`)

  // Create the "MonthYear" string.
  const monthYear = (() => {
    const date = new Date()
    const month = [
      `Jan`, `Feb`, `Mar`, `Apr`,
      `May`, `Jun`, `Jul`, `Aug`,
      `Sep`, `Oct`, `Nov`, `Dec`
    ][date.getMonth()]
    const year = String(date.getFullYear()).slice(-2)

    return `${month}${year}`
  })()

  // Copy/rename masterWorksheet to specified folder.
  DriveApp
    .getFileById(masterWorksheetId)
    .makeCopy(`${monthYear}worksheet`, destinationFolder)

  // Copy/rename masterSchedule to specified folder.
  const newSchedule = DriveApp
    .getFileById(masterScheduleId)
    .makeCopy(`${monthYear}schedule`, destinationFolder)

  // Open the new schedule sheet..
  SpreadsheetApp
    .openById(newSchedule.getId())
    .getSheets()
    // For each sheet..
    .forEach((sheet) => {

      const range = sheet.getDataRange()
      // Get the values of the sheet..
      const values = range.getValues()

      const newValues = range
        // As well as the formulas..
        .getFormulas()
        // For each row of the sheet..
        .map((row, rowIndex) => {
          return row
            .map((cell, cellIndex) => (cell !== ``)
              // If the cell contains a formula, replace any instance of 'master' with 'monthYear`.
              ? cell.replace(/master/g, monthYear)
              // If the cell does not contain a formula, place the cell value instead.
              : values[rowIndex][cellIndex]
            )
        })

      // Update the sheet with newValues
      range.setValues(newValues)
      
    })

  // Just for safety.
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()

}
```

Comment: Why `[...row]` instead of just `row`?`.map` already makes a copy.

Comment: @TheMaster Nice flex

Comment: Long before, I noticed spread operator was extremely slow(relative to other ops) in Apps script(not sure how it is now). That's why I added a comment.